# Adblock Plus - whitelisting rule

Tags: filter, adblock

I have an element that looks like this on the page:

```
<a data-mytype="myvalue" href="http://example.com/promo/page">...</a>
```

This element gets hidden by the following ABP rule (present in one of the filter subscriptions I use):

```
##[href*="/promo"]
```

How do I write a whitelisting rule that will exclude that element from being hidden by Adblock Plus based on a specific attribute/value pair - like the `data-mytype="myvalue"` one?

I have checked the [Writing Adblock Plus filters](https://adblockplus.org/filters) and [Adblock Plus filters explained](https://adblockplus.org/filter-cheatsheet) pages, but I have not figured out how to (successfully) write a filter based on the specified attribute.

Both pages mention that standard CSS selectors should work, however this does not seem to work:

```
@@a[data-mytype="myvalue"]
```

I have also tried the following:

```
#@#[href*="/promo"][data-mytype="myvalue"]
```

What am I missing?

Note: I do not want a rule that will just cancel out the `##[href*="/promo"]`, I am looking for a rule that will whitelist elements only based on a specific attribute/value pair.

**Edit (2016-03-17)**: Clarified my question a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first disable the existing rule:

```
#@#[href*="/promo"]
```

Note that the selector has to be identical, otherwise element hiding exceptions won't apply. Then you can add your own rule, one that will consider the `data-mytype` attribute:

```
##[href*="/promo"]:not([data-mytype="myvalue"])
```

The combination of these two rules should have the effect you want. For reference: [:not() CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: So ABP does not whitelist elements that are blacklisted without explicitly cancelling out the blacklisting rule? I thought that the whitelist was prioritized overt the blaclist. Basically, that ABP will make a list of elements to be hidden based on the blacklisting rules and then remove from that list any elements that match whitelisting rules, all this before actually hiding said elements.

Comment: @SilviuG: Element hiding exceptions don't apply to elements, they apply to element hiding rules. So the selector part of the rule has to be identical, otherwise it won't work. This has technical reasons, detecting that multiple rules matched the same element and deciding which one of those should be applied isn't possible.

Comment: Thank you for the technical reasons clarification. It is not the answer I was hoping for, but at least now I have something solid to work with.

Comment: Note: The closing bracket for the `:not` expression is missing. Otherwise, it works as advertised

Answer (score 0):

The rule `###yourdiv` can be disabled by `#@##yourdiv` (`##.yourclass` by `#@#.yourclass`)

In your case : `#@#[data-mytype="myvalue"]`

Comment: I have clarified my question a little bit, please re-examine it.

Comment: What about `@@||example.com^$elemhide` or `@@||example.com^$generichide`
if not that what you are looking for give me an example with links already hidden by Adblock Plus + Easylist.

Comment: The test page contains sample links. Also, I can't include example.com in my rule, I need a generic rule that would work on any domain.